# Javascript changing images is not always working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a menu with images.
I have 2 divs with 3 images inside each so i make it to look like a menu.  When I click the above image the image under it changes to highlight the above.

The JavaScript works but if I click the images many times some times its not working properly.
So how can I be certain that JavaScript wont lag? I cant figure out if its coding problem or placement or anything else...

By not working Properly i mean that if i click the images a lot of times  some times the image that should change to highlight the top image arent changing i dont know if its my computer or not..
Here is Code http://codepen.io/DarkLord22/pen/Ghwbj

```
<div class="Menu1">
<div id="Menu1_1">
<img src="images/menu1/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu1_1.jpg" width="395" height="300" onclick="changeImage1() , removeImage1()"></div>
<div id="Menu1_1">
<img src="images/menu1/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu1_2.jpg" width="395" height="300" onclick="changeImage2(), removeImage2()">
</div>
<div id="Menu1_1">
<img src="images/menu1/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_menu1_3.jpg" width="395" height="300" onclick="changeImage3(), removeImage3()">
```

```
<div id="Menubluebuttondiv">
    <div id="Menubluebutton">
      <img src="images/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_blue_arrow.jpg" width="395" height="42" id="toChange1"></div>
    <div id="Menubluebutton">
         <img src="images/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_Bluearrow2.jpg" width="395" height="42" id="toChange2">
    </div>
    <div id="Menubluebutton">
        <img src="images/Landing_Campaign_Smartwatch_Bluearrow2.jpg" width="395" height="42" id="toChange3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seem to work fine for me

Comment: "its not working properly". What behavior do you get? And what did you expect? In addition: please include the minimal code that is needed to reproduce your problem in the question. While a codepen is great, the question should contain the relevant code too.

Comment: You're using the `id` property as a class. ID's should be used to identify one particular div. A class is used to work with elements that should have matching behavior.

Comment: To add on to what Brian said, you should never use the same ID twice. They should be unique. You can get some really strange behavior when you use duplicate IDs.